# How to convert date based on current users, using client side code

Tags: 2013, javascript, date-time

I have a date that I want to display to the user, and the format should be dynamic and based on the user. If I do this I get a format that doesn't fit every user.

```
var prettyDate = originalDate.format('dd MMM yyy, hh:ss');
```

For example, in Sweden we would like it displayed as `2014-03-04` but another country would want it as `4/3 2014` 
So instead of explicitly writing the format in the code, I want to get the preferred date format for the current user. My idea was that I could maybe use the culture found in _spPageContextInfo, or something in SP.DateTimeUtil, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Ajax library also contains [Date.localeFormat Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383816%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that formats a date by using the current culture.

Example:

```
var prettyDate = originalDate.localeFormat('dd MMM yyy, hh:ss');
console.log(prettyDate);
```

Comment: But that still means I have to put in a format string and I don't want to do that. What I want is to use the same rendering of the date as used by SharePoint default, for example in a list

Comment: @stinaq did you see the example `dateVar.localeFormat(Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);`? As a last resort perhaps look at http://momentjs.com/